# Exporting a value to TextField in JAVA from keyPressed

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to know how to export value in continuous to TextField in the JFrame ,, there is a circle that is moving and I am calculating its velocity ,I want this velocity to be displayed in the TextField every time it changes its velocity , but the problem is i can't get the value out of the (public void (keyPressed(KeyEvent e )) and take it to the main method to display it in the TextField (field.setText(Double.toString(velx));)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXQMu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkTo0.jpg)

```
public class All extends JComponent implements ActionListener, KeyListener {


Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
double x=0 , y=0;
static double velx=0 ,vely=0;




public All() {
    t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;


     g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
     g2.setColor(Color.red);
     g2.drawLine(10, 300, 1990, 300);
     g2.setColor(Color.blue);
     g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,40,40));
     g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
     g2.setColor(Color.green);
     g2.drawRect(900, 500, 700,400);
 }

 public void up() {
    vely=vely-0.5;
    velx = 0;

 }
 public void down() {
    vely=vely+0.5;
    velx = 0;
}
public void left() {
velx=velx-0.5;
vely = 0;
 }
  public void right() {


velx=velx+0.5;
vely = 0;

 }
 public static void stop() {
 velx=0;
 vely=0;
 }




 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
 int code = e.getKeyCode();



if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
    up(); 
    if(x>900 && x<1577 && y>500 && y<860) {
 System.out.println("up: "+(-1*vely)+"/s");

    }
}




if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
down();
if(x>900 && x<1577 && y>500 && y<860) {
System.out.println("down: "+vely+"/s");
 }}




 if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
     right(); 
     if((x<=1880 && x>=-7 && y>=262 && y<=288 ) || (x>900 && x<1577 && y>500 
    && y<860 )) {
      System.out.println("right: "+velx+"/s");
      }
   }



   if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
    left(); 
    if(x<=1880 && x>=-7 && y>=262 && y<=288 ||  (x>900 && x<1577 && y>500 && 
    y<860)) {
        System.out.println("left: "+(-1*velx)+"/s");}
}
 if(code == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    stop();
   }

    }
```

the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

JLabel velocity = new JLabel("Velocity");
JLabel change = new JLabel("Change");
JFrame frame = new JFrame("APPLICATION");
Button button = new Button("Mode 2");


TextField field = new TextField();      



change.setBounds(30, 486, 150,50);
velocity.setBounds(30, 400, 150,50);
button.setBounds(150, 500, 150,30);    
field.setBounds(150, 415, 150,30);



velocity.setForeground(Color.white);        
velocity.setFont(new Font("sansserif",Font.PLAIN, 30));

change.setForeground(Color.white);
change.setFont(new Font("sansserif",Font.PLAIN, 30));


  button.setFont(new Font("serif",Font.PLAIN, 18));
  field.setFont(new Font("serif",Font.PLAIN, 18));   


    frame.setContentPane(new All());
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.pack();


     frame.add(field);
     frame.add(button);
     frame.add(velocity);
    frame.add(change);

    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);




    field.setText(Double.toString(velx));




       button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
              if(e.getActionCommand()=="Mode 2"){
                  All2.main(args);
             frame.setVisible(false);
              stop();
              }
                      }  
                }); 
   }


 @Override
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

 }

 @Override
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    repaint();
    x += velx;
    y += vely;

    if(x>=1885) {
        x=1885;
        stop();
    }

 if(y>=1010) {
    y=1010;
    stop(); 
  }
  if(y>=372 && y<374 && x<300 ) {
    stop();up();

  }if(x<300 && (y>374 && y<524) ) {

     stop();right();
 }if( x<300 && y>=524 && y<526) {
     stop();down();
 }

if(x<=-7) {
    x=-7;
     stop();
 }
 if(y<=-5) {
    y=-5;
    stop();
 }

  }







 }
```

Comment: So, somewhere, you should have a value/variable which represents the velocity. You need to setup a "state changed" event which, when the value of the velocity is changed, is triggered. You would then listen for this event and update the field accordingly

Comment: Your code should not be in the main() method. You need to restructure your class better. Take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html). It shows how to update a text area when a key is typed. If you understand that simple design you should be able to redesign your class.

Comment: the variable that represents the velocity is (velx) .. I only have the frame ..etc in the main method .. how can i have the velx of the keyPressed in the main method ??

Comment: You don't. The main method should be used to create the GUI hook up any and all components (model-view-controller) and then make the GUI visible, and that's it.

Comment: OK, thanks for posting the code. My first and main recommendation is fix that main method as I described above. None of that code should be in the main method and instead should be composed of instance (non-static) fields initialized in constructors or instance methods, and the main method should just serve to create the main GUI and set it visible.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways to approach this problem, including those suggested in the comments on your question which involve hooking the GUI stuff up correctly so that changes are noticed automatically and populated without you doing much work.

A quick and dirty solution is to have a global variable for that field.

```
TextField yourTextField; // <-- global variable (initialized somewhere)
```

Then you can actually update it's text directly from keyPressed(...) either every time a key gets pressed (see example below) or you could squeeze it inside any of the key checks that might update it.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // ... all the other stuff

    textField.setText( Double.toString(velx) );
}
```

It could also be updated in the right(), left(), etc methods. However either of those approaches are kind of ugly and neither recommended nor the proper way of handling it.

I'm not sure what the *ideal* way of doing this would be in Java, but one way is simply to run some kind of regular UI update which checks all the fields you want the UI to display the values of.

update function

```
void updateUI() {
    // ... whatever else needs doing

    if( !textField.getText().equals( Double.toString(velx) ) ) {
        textField.setText( Double.toString(velx) );
    }
}
```

Then call that function in the main program somewhere.

```
void mainLoop() {
    updateUI()
}
```

Another is to adjust your functions so that when you adjust those values you also tick some box which would trigger a conditional UI update.

global (or other scope) variable that you change when the value of a particular variable is changed.

```
boolean velx_changed = false;
```

change value and mark for update

```
velx++;
velx_changed = true;
```

the stuff that happens in the main program

```
void mainLoop() {
    if( velx_changed ) {
        textField.setText( Double.toString(velx) );
    }
}
```

Comment: i will posted public

Answer (score -1):

THANK YOU GUYS .. I used static TextField in the class and then i just added it to the frame in the main method

```
    static TextField field = new TextField();
```

in the keyPressed

```
      if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
       right();  field.setText(Double.toString(velx));
      if((x<=1880 && x>=-7 && y>=262 && y<=288 ) || (x>900 && x<1577 && y>500 
      && y<860 )) {
      System.out.println("right: "+velx+"/s");
      }
     }
```

in the main method

```
frame.add(field);
```

Comment: This is so wrong in so many ways. Please re-think and re-code, lest you paint yourself in a corner. You've gotten advice from 3 of the highest rated Swing experts on this site, and yet you choose to ignore it. Why?

Comment: i am not ignoring .. actually its working because of your advices.